# C# WPF-Ask user before closing application if right-clicking the application icon on the system task bar

Tags: c#, wpf

Let say I click the close button in my application and it will popup a dialog box with yes and no option. How can I implement this (popup dialog box ask user whether want to close the application) if I close the application by right-clicking the application icon on the system task bar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Subscribe to Closing event in your MainWindow:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Closing += OnClosing;
}

private void OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs cancelEventArgs)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show(this, "Your message", "Confirm", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        cancelEventArgs.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nguyen Kien, thanks for your solution, but my close button is an image and the dialog box is a wpf window, so do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @YWah The `Closing` event is raised when the window should close. Nguyens solution works with all kinds of closing a WPF window (`Close` method is called or the user clicked the Close button).